# How does damage work in the Ys series?

Tags: ys-series

I'm asking this question as I replay the series because once again, the weird damage system seems very strange. It's most pronounced in Ys 1, where changing equipment or levelling up to slightly increase your attack stat (by like ten points; end-of-game maximum is 255 so this isn't much of a difference) can be the difference between doing 1 damage per hit and doing something like 30 or even 50 damage a hit. But then adding more attack on top of that hardly changes the damage at all. Defense is in a similar situation, where there seems to be some threshold (different for each enemy) below which you take a ton of damage and above which adding more defense doesn't seem to do much.

So... what's the formula being used here? Has anyone looked into the code of any of the various remakes?

This unusual system where a small stat change leads to large differences in damage given/taken is still present in Ys II, and to a lesser degree in The Oath in Felghana. I've yet to get to any of the later games in the series, so I can't say whether they kept it or went with something more conventional, though.